# when does a memory become available to a program?

Tags: c, pointers

I have this two programs just for understanding how pointers work. The first one is named `test.c` and here is the code.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
int main(void)
{
int *mem = malloc(sizeof(int) * 1);
*mem = 90;
//free(mem);
printf("%p", mem);
return (0);
}
```

so basically what I have is a program that allocates a place for one integer then prints that address to the standard output. In the commented section I am freeing the allocated memory after assigning a value. I will talk about why I commented it later. Here is my second code. It is in a file called `test1.c`. And here is the code,

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
int num = (int)strtol(argv[1], NULL, 16);
int *mem = (void *)(long)num;

printf("at test1 string> %s, changed to pointer-->%p, after being dereferenced-->%i\n",argv[1], mem, *mem);
return (0);
}
```

In this second program, an input is taken from the command line and then it is changed to a pointer (an address). It assumes what is passed is a hex string. What it does, is just to print the memory address passed and then try to get the value at that address.

What I did next is to compile each file to `test` and `test1` respectively using gcc (I am using linux) and run the following command `./test | xargs ./test1` and this gives me the following error `xargs: ./test1: terminated by signal 11`. I have understood that this is because of the segmentation fault test1 is raising because if I don't try to dereference the pointer I don't get this error. But I don't understand why I am getting a seg fault. even after I free the memory (uncomment the comment in the first program) I still get a segmentation fault. I was expecting to get some garbage value rather than a seg fault.I am getting started with this whole process and pointer thing so for sure there is something I am missing, I hope someone will explain or direct me to a resource.

To just reprahse my question, **how can a program access a specific memory without allocating it**?

Comment: <hacker>:Oh look, my web app just scanned all memory, because all programs can see all memory in 70s OS, and found some belonging to super secret app.  Let's have some fun...

Comment: On a PC there is only a certain range of address that your program may access, and anyway they are not physical addresses, and the range may change from one run to the next. If you should obtain an address from one program and try putting it into another, that is perfectly useless (by design).

Comment: @MichaelDorgan too bad I wasn't born in the 70s

Comment: I worked on original GameBoy games.  That was a system where the above would work...

Comment: @MichaelDorgan cool that is very insighitfull. Little did I know, after learning about pointers I wanted to make a program that would read what is in every bit of memory. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't.

Memory address are divided into pages (usually 4096 bytes). When you access an address, the CPU looks up the page with that address in the process's "page table". This table says where in *physical memory* (i.e. "which RAM chip") that address is.

So you cannot access addresses that aren't in your process's page table. Full stop.

How do you get pages added to your page table? You ask the OS. On Windows the function is called `VirtualAlloc`. On Linux it's called `mmap`. Or, you use a function like `malloc`, which lets you allocate only a small part of a page (by splitting up the pages it gets from the OS).

Also, every process has a different page table. So the addresses mean different things in different processes. Maybe the `test` process could have a page table entry for page 0x12345000, but the `test1` process doesn't, because they're completely different tables. This is why it doesn't make sense to send pointers from one process to another.

In the old days of computing, there were no page tables and pointers were actual RAM addresses, but those days are long gone.

Edit: You can also ask the OS to put the same page in two different processes' page tables at the same time - this is called *shared memory*.

Answer (score 3):

So if I understand what you are doing, you're printing the address of a dynamically allocated block of memory from one program, cutting and pasting that as input to a second program, which then tries to access that address.

There are several reasons why this won't work.

First is what user253751 points out - addresses don't map across different processes.  `0x1234` in process A maps to a different physical memory cell than `0x1234` in process B.  There are ways of setting up shared memory between running processes, but it's a bit more work than this.

Secondly, you're using the wrong types.  An `int` is not large enough to store a pointer value - after casting and assigning the result of `strtol` to `num` you've certainly lost some digits, so casting that back to a pointer won't get you the right address.

The types `intptr_t` and `uintptr_t` in `stddef.h` are integer types large enough to store pointer values, but their implementation is optional, and it's still not a sure bet that `strtol` can accurately convert the input value.

Comment: Ok thanks. Thank you for all the lessons, I will read more about the things you have mentiond.

Answer (score 1):

While user253751 has given a good technical explanation, i want to put it more beginner-friendly:
Your OS makes sure one process cannot access the memory of another one as this would mean that you could manipulate or destroy other programs or steal their data (passwords, for example).
The C language does not check pointers, so you can set them to whatever you want, but if you want to access this address, the OS is stopping you because it has security features.

Comment: Ok thanks. I have learned about virtual allocation by asking this question thanks you all.